# How can I create a file via an XCode run-script and add to project?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I want to display my git version on my app. From some research, it looks like I can accomplish this via a run-script.

This code below will create a file at `Resources/GitVersion.swift`

```
version=$(git rev-parse --verify HEAD | cut -c 1-10)
commitDate=$(git log -n 1 HEAD --pretty=format:"%h - %cd" | cut -c 12-)

filesource="//\n//  GitVersion.swift\n//\n//  Commit Date:$commitDate\n//\n\nlet gitVersion = \"$version\"\n"
cd ${SOURCE_ROOT}/${PROJECT_NAME}

echo "$filesource" > Resources/GitVersion.swift

touch Resources/GitVersion.swift
```

The file will look like: `let gitVersion = XXX`, and will update each time the code runs.

Great, except `GitVersion.swift` isn't in my project, so I can't reference gitVersion anywhere to access the git hash.

How can I add `GitVersion.swift` via a runscript to my project, such that every time I run my build, it creates the file and dynamically adds the dependency to the project?

Comment: Is it really a requirement for the adding of the file to also happen automatically? If not, you can just drag and drop the file into xcode. Running your script again will then update the contents of the file each time.

Comment: The reason I don't want to add the file into my xcode project manually is because I want to use `.gitignore` for the file. Otherwise you end up with a weird scenario where you add the file and commit, then next time you run your project is dirty, git wants to update because now the hash has changed, so you add file and commit again, and it becomes cumbersome

Comment: Okay actually @SanderSaelmans your suggestion works -- I can add the file manually, then add to gitignore and remove cached tracking. Thanks -- if you want to answer the question I will mark yours as the solution since it solved my problem!